# Inbox messages in rails like facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to create a personal inbox message system but couple question are on my mind. First let me explain my system.

Here is my table model

```
  create_table "inboxmessages", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "receiver_id"
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.integer  "message_id"
    t.boolean  "isread"
    t.boolean  "isstarred"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end

  create_table "messages", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "subject"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

The relationship would be has follow

```
inboxmessages
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
messages
  has_many :inboxmessages
user
  has_many :inboxmessages
```

The problem that i am having his i am uncertain on how to create a message which allows me multiple users. here the schema of the form i am trying to have

```
Message.subject
Inboxmessage.receiver # but have multiple different user
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Message.body
Inboxmessage.sender = current_user # hidden field
```

Here are the question that I have regarding building this model/controller/app

```
1 - Should my new form be in inboxmessages or messages?
2 - Should I use accept_nested_for or should I use nested resources
3 - Is my model/database is okay or not the best?
4 - Are my foreign_key relationship well define?
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
class User
  has_many :mailboxes
  has_many :messages, :through => :tags
  has_many :tags
end

class Message
  has_many :users, :through => :tags
  has_many :mailboxes, :through => :tags
  has_many :tags
end

class Mailbox
  has_many :tags
  has_many :messages, :through => :tags
  has_many :users, :through => tags
end

class Tag
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :mailbox
  # this class has "read?", "starred", etc.
end
```

This enables a message to appear in multiple mailboxes, for multiple users, and each user can have his/her own "read?", "starred", etc. You can limit the logic if you want to ensure that a user has only one copy of a message, i.e. the message is not in two or more mailboxes for the same user.

To improve your schema, read the Rails Guides, especially about *associations* like these:

- belongs_to
- has_one
- has_many
- has_many :through
- inverse_of

Also look at the Rails gem *acts-as-taggable-on*

- http://rubygems.org/gems/acts-as-taggable-on

One way to think of a message schema is "a message belongs to a mailbox, and a mailbox has many messages" (this is how Yahoo does it). Another way to think of a message is "a message has many tags, and a mailbox is simply a search by tag" (this is how Gmail does it).

By the way, the Ruby *mail* gem is excellent. You can use it for creating messages, and look at how it converts headers like from, to, cc, etc.

You asked good questions:

- 1 - Should my new form be in inboxmessages or messages?

  My opinion is that you will get the most benefit if you have a model for the message that is like an email, have a model for a mailbox (or tag). To create a new message, the new form would typically be in ./messages/new.html.erb
- 2 - Should I use accept_nested_for or should I use nested resources?

Nested resources are fine; see the Rails guide here:

```
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources
```

Nested attributes are also fine; see the API here:

A good rule of thumb is to only nest one level down, because after that it gets more complicated than its worth.

- 3 - Is my model/database is okay or not the best?

Not the best. A real-world message will typically have a sender and receiver(s). But you're modeling the sender and receiver in the inboxmessages table. Better to model the message with has_many receivers, and use a separate model for the user's interaction with the message for example a table called "marks" with fields "starred", "isread", etc. A mark belongs to a message and belongs to a user. A message has_many marks, and a user has_many marks.

- 4 - Are my foreign_key relationship well define?

In general, yes. Just be aware that email is surprisingly hard to model. A good rule of thumb is to index your foreign keys. Also look at Rails associations "inverse_of" and use it; this will help with speed and memory use.

Comment: Why have a mailbox table?

Comment: @Nicholas A mailbox table is very useful for organizing the mail; for example, the user can have multiple mailboxes such as "Inbox", "Home", "Work", "Spam", etc.

Comment: Would this approach work with a single mailbox application? More like a message queue?

Comment: @Nicholas Your question doesn't have enough info for me to be able to answer; I suggest you can post your question with more detail, as a new StackOverflow question, so more people here can help you.

Comment: Thanks @joelparkerhenderson - here's the [link to my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023051/modeling-a-messaging-database-in-rails). Really appreciated your thorough response.

Answer (score 1):

I would have my classes set up something like this.

```
class Inbox
  has_many :messages
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :messages
  has_one :inbox
end

class Message
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :inbox
  has_many recipients, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "recipient_id"
end
```